# How to make an HTTP GET request to OWIN self hosted API?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, api, owin

I'm very new to web development but I wanted to create a web api for an existing Windows Service application I created for work.

My goal right now is to create a simple web app consisting of some text input fields where someone can enter their email and subscribe to a mailing list.

I was pointed in the direction of using OWIN to self-host a web api in my existing project so I looked at this guide to get started:

https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

This guide shows the console app calling and displaying the API, but I wanted to do the same from a web app. So I tried to do what is accomplished here in the '[Getting Started with ASP.NET Web Api 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)' guide using a console application with OWIN.

When I start my console application, I can enter `http://localhost:8080/api/values/1` and I get `<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">value</string>` Which I assume means the web server is running and responds to the request to get my string value that I'm returning from my ValuesController.

However I've been trying to create a simple web page that calls the API to get the `value` but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Right now my index.html has the following in the body:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var uri = "http://localhost:8080/api/values/1";

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON(uri)
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#value').text("done");
        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            $('#value').text('Error: ' + err);
        });

    });
</script>
```

And I just get `Error:` printed on the page. Again I'm new to working on web related technologies so any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do the developer tools say? They can be pretty helpful when debugging! Also, if youre using chrome you can put a breakpoint in the javascript and see what the jqxhr and textStatus object are. At the moment you just throw them away, they might be useful!

Comment: Also, the postman tool, either as a standalone app or chrome plugin is very useful for testing api endpoints.. Might be worth making sure your api is up using postman, then working on the javascript. No point getting confused if your api isnt working!

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the comment. I'm trying to navigate my way through these tools still!

I used the Postman chrome plugin, and sent GET with http://localhost:8080/api/values/1 

and "value" showed up in the body which I think means that the api worked.

Comment: jqHXR is ' Object {readyState: 4, responseJSON: undefined, status: 404, statusText: "error"}'

and textStatus is 'error'

Comment: Ok, and where are you running the webpage? How are you hosting it? What ports as well? Is it a different port to the api?

Comment: I've just created index.html in Visual Studio as part of my solution. I open that html file in the browser.
Could that be the issue? I'm not properly running the webpage?

Comment: I wonder if you are running jnto cross-domain issues, (look at jsonp and cors) and also not hosting properly. What does chrome developer tools say? Any info?

Comment: I've seen those terms (JSONp, CORS) while trying to research my problem but didn't know what they were or if they applied at the time, I'll look into those.

In the console in the developer tools I'm getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/values/1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.` So maybe it is related to CORS?

I'm definitely going to look into that now.

Comment: Thats the problem then, because you are trying to access a different port or url to get data, the browser blocks your request. Any way to host the web page in your webapi app? Then you would bypass the whole issue as it comes from the same source.

Comment: After a while at looking at samples and questions I found out how to host the web page from the app with the api. And it worked! The webpage starts when I run the console app and it's able to use the api. Now hopefully I can connect this to my existing app. Thanks a lot! If you post an answer I'll mark it solved.

Comment: glad to hear it! Cross-Origin requests cause such a pain for api requests :( at least you know how to use the tools now to help debug with anything in the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, following the discussion in comments (helping you to debug the app).
The cross-origin security policy in browsers restricts web pages from calling an data source that exists on a different domain. A domain is either a different url, or a different port at the same url.

> http://localhost:80

is a different url/domain from:

> http://localhost:81

There are two solutions to this, either utilise JSONP, or CORS to make the request to the api, JSONP basically wraps your json data up in a function call. When the api call returns, it executes the callback/function call, bypassing the security restriction. 
However, both JSONP and CORS require server support, which brings solution 2...

Serve up the webpage you are trying to use from the API, meaning you server it from the same domain, hence no cross-domain issues!!

Glad you have got it sorted, I know it can be frustrating with web calls.